# Add a day to a date AND time string

Tags: r, date, time, addition

I would like to advance a date and time string in R by one day, keeping the time.

```
datetime<-"2015-07-20T16:33:59.158Z"

as.Date(datetime)+1
as.POSIXct(datetime)+24*60*60

library(lubridate)
as.POSIXct(datetime)+days(1)
as.POSIXct(datetime)+hours(24)
```

All return either

```
 "2015-07-21"
 "2015-07-21 BST"
```

when what is required is

```
"2015-07-21T16:33:59.158Z"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the output for

```
as.POSIXct(datetime)
#[1] "2015-07-20"
```

it truncates the time component. You need to specify proper `format` to it since it is not in standard format.

```
as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
#[1] "2015-07-20 16:33:59
```

Once you do that you can do

```
as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS") + 24*60*60
#[1] "2015-07-21 16:33:59"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do as below:

```
library(lubridate)
datetime <- ymd_hms("2015-07-20T16:33:59.158Z")
datetime + 24*60*60
[1] "2015-07-21 16:33:59 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anytime(datetime) + 24 * 60 * 60
#[1] "2015-07-21 16:33:59 EDT"
```